# Random Problem about Graph Cartesian Product

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to solve an interesting problem I came up with:

Suppose you have a graph cartesian product G cross H, using the following definition of the product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs

Suppose further that the following property holds: there is an independent set in $G\times H$ with at least one vertex in each 'copy' of H that appears in G.

Is it necessarily true that there is an independent set in the resulting graph G' formed by "gluing" together vertices from different copies of H which still has the property that there is at least one vertex in each copy of H?

Note that after the gluing together of two vertices into a single vertex $v$, if $v$ falls in the independent set it now counts toward both copies of H that were glued together in regard to satisfying the required property.

I am guessing that this is not true in general, but curious what you guys think.